# ASP.NET WebApi : Response GZIP compression not effective

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2, compression

I have an ASP.NET WEB API with compression enabled. In my WebApiConfig.cs, i have

```
config.MessageHandlers.Insert(
     0,
     new ServerCompressionHandler(
               new GZipCompressor(),
               new DeflateCompressor()
    )
);
```

It seems to work: when I do a request with PostMan, i get a response with ContentEncoding = gzip, and ContentLength is 300ko, the compressed size.

But with the following C# code, in my client (console program):

```
            HttpWebRequest apiRequest = WebRequest.CreateHttp("http://localhost:8085/data");
        apiRequest.Method = "GET";
        apiRequest.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip | DecompressionMethods.Deflate;
        apiRequest.Accept = "application/json";

        HttpWebResponse apiResponse;
        try
        {
            apiResponse = (HttpWebResponse)apiRequest.GetResponse();
        }
        catch (WebException ex)
        {
            apiResponse = ex.Response as HttpWebResponse;
            if (apiResponse == null)
            {
                throw;
            }
        }


        var sr = new StreamReader(apiResponse.GetResponseStream());
        string ct = sr.ReadToEnd(); // Full result in string


        var respEncoding = apiResponse.ContentEncoding; // empty string  
        var respLen = apiResponse.ContentLength; // -1
```

the ContentLength is set to -1, and the contentEncoding is empty. Howewer, I can get the full content in a string.
Can you explain me why ?

Comment: It seems that replacing apiRequest.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip | DecompressionMethods.Deflate;  by
            apiRequest.Headers["Accept-Encoding"] = "gzip";            works. But why ?

Comment: Examine http headers. `HttpWebRequest` is really low level, it only does what you asked. Use a debug proxy, like Fiddler to inspect the differences between Postman and your client.

Comment: It is quite subjective to explain why something works the way it works, because it just works like that, especially when it is by-design.

Answer (score 2):

> the ContentLength is set to -1, and the contentEncoding is empty. Howewer, I can get the full content in a string. Can you explain me why ?

This is by design, check out [this link](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#system/net/System/Net/HttpWebResponse.cs,56efb02779605cf2). `HttpWebResponse` class it-self explicitly sets those values when `Content-Encoding` header is `Gzip` or `Deflate` and `AutomaticDecompression` flag is set.

> It seems that replacing apiRequest.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip | DecompressionMethods.Deflate; by apiRequest.Headers["Accept-Encoding"] = "gzip"; works. But why ?

What do you mean by it works?
If you mean you get original values for `ContentEncoding` and `ContentLength` then it is because your response hasn't been decompressed.

If you want to get original values from headers when using `AutomaticDecompression` flag then use `Headers[header-key]` to get original value from the response (in this case `apiResponse.Headers["Content-Length"]` will be length of compressed data). However, only catch is you will loose original value of `Content-Encoding` for some weird reason as explained in the referenced code.

```
// Setting a response header after parsing will ruin the Common Header optimization.
// This seems like a corner case.  ContentEncoding could be added as a common header, with a special
// property allowing it to be nulled.
m_HttpResponseHeaders[HttpKnownHeaderNames.ContentEncoding] = null;
```

Comment: Thank you ! When I say "it works", I mean I had good values for ContentEncoding, and ContentLength, and my content is not decompressed (this is what I need).

Answer (score 0):

If your API is behind firewall it will strip out the headers, as a result you will fail to see the response, postman does not take that into account.

see also:

[Even Faster Web Sites: Performance Best Practices for Web Developers By Steve Souders](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=E7p-07kNfXYC&pg=PA124&lpg=PA124&dq=headers%20stripped%20by%20norton&source=bl&ots=UNdpSLjiMs&sig=2IHevXbVmr93x2tzG6FN17W4ZKk&hl=en&sa=X&ei=vDQ6VdayLYXOO6G4gIAF&ved=0CCsQ6AEwAg#v=onepage&q=headers%20stripped%20by%20norton&f=false)

Comment: Thanks for your answer (at least, there is one), but I have no firewall.